# how to use Ansible clone git submodule with username/password login

Tags: git, ansible, git-submodules

I am trying use ansible git module to clone a work project.
This project and all submodule are on a private server, and use username/password authentication. I can hardcode (or var on hosts file) the account in main project url, But ansible hangs because I must answer submodule login info.

Is there anyway to pass login info for submodule update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways, as documented in [git-credentials fine manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html):

- using `git config` to specify the static credentials for a given set of remotes
- using a "credential helper" to dynamically provide credentials
- using the well established [`.netrc`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/netrc.5.html) *(which is the way I have the most experience solving that problem in CI/CD pipelines)*

There are several branching paths to the answer, depending on whether your situation will allow you to write out a `.netrc` or even a temporary `.gitconfig` containing the static credentials as described in that page. So, if this doesn't answer your question, then provide more details

Answer (score 0):

@mdaniel
thank you for infomation.now i use .netrc .i am write ansible task like this:

```
- name: git login username
      pause:
        prompt: "git login username"
      register: git_user_input
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: git_user is not defined

    - name: git login password
      pause:
        prompt: "git login password"
      register: git_pass_input
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: git_pass is not defined
    - set_fact: git_user={{git_user_input.user_input}}
      when: git_user is not defined
    - set_fact: git_pass={{git_pass_input.user_input}}
      when: git_pass is not defined

    - name: set git login info
      copy:
        dest: /home/user/.netrc
        content: |
          machine common.internal.computer
          login {{git_user}}
          password {{git_pass}}

    - name: git clone main project
      git:
        accept_hostkey: yes
        version: devel-office
        dest: "{{target_dir}}/main"
        repo: "http://{{mainuser}}:{{mainpass}}@git.work.computer/main.git"
    - name: delete git login info
      file:
        path: /home/user/.netrc
        state: absent
```

first step is ask input git account,save to var git_user and git_pass
then clone main project,with different account from inventory file.
when ansible try update submodule,it let git use infomation from .netrc.works fine.
finally.remove .netrc file.

use other method,looks same,all must create file:.git-config or .git-credentials.just different content.i choose .netrc because it is look more clear and human readable.and at last step ,all need remove login infomation from remote computer.